# Can we use the phrase "good recovering day"? Is it grammatically correct? Can it be used to be understood by a wider audience?

Tags: grammar, phrases

I'm having a minor surgery and I need to postpone a session with one of my clients from France. She wrote to me this sentence: "*I wish you a good recovering Saturday*". I certainly think this is **not** idiomatic, but I still want to check the grammatical correctness of this sentence and the associated phrases, below.

I'm aware that we can use the phrase 'recovery day', but I've the following questions:

1. Can we use 'recovering day' to mean 'day of recovery' or 'recovery day'?
2. Can we use 'recovery Sunday' ... is it grammatically correct?
3. Can we use 'good recovering day' grammatically (if not idiomatically)? Or should we rather use 'good recovery Sunday', if the answer to 2) was a yes? The point here is putting two adjectives together: 'good' and 'recovery'. I know two adjectives can coexist, but is it okay to use like that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just because a phrase is grammatically correct doesn't mean that it's widely understood or even understandable.

Comment: I have downvoted as the OP has not given the sentence and context in which the phrase will be used: the question lacks necessary detail.

Comment: @Greybeard I edited the question with necessary detail - I hope you take your downvote back :)

Comment: But what is the person being addressed recovering _from_?

Comment: If they're not ill, just working hard, then "have a relaxing weekend" would be fine. Beyond that, it depends on the context: from manager to staff, staff to manager, and whether you've been working closely. It could be seen as patronising or insulting to imply someone is exhausted and unable to keep up with their work. ("Recovery day" has a particular meaning as a special day off when you've worked exceptionally long hours or are jet-lagged, but doesn't seem to apply here.)

Comment: @KateBunting from France. I'm still trying to think what made her think of this expression? I'd guess some direct translation is at play here, but with my intermdiate knowledge of French, I'm having trouble. I know that they translate 'bon appétit' as 'good appetite' which is wrong in English. But I don't know what they say for when they want to wish someone to recover.

Comment: She could have said something like "I wish you a good Saturday to recover from your trip to France" (assuming that's what you mean).

Comment: @StuartF Please see the added detail that'd fill up the rest of the context.

Comment: @KateBunting Nobody is taking a trip, neither me, nor my client from France. However, I'm having a minor surgery and so am taking a break from my usual Sunday sessions with that client. Hence she wanted to wish me a relaxing day to recover, but expressed using that sentence. I edited the OP, see.

Comment: We got our wires crossed. I asked _what someone was recovering from_, and you answered 'from France', so I  supposed you meant a journey there!  'A day to recover in' would still be appropriate, though.

Comment: @KateBunting Sorry about that! Yes I agree with the last sentence.

Comment: No one mentioned the possibility of a literal translation: *Une bonne récupération samedi*. (Google Translate, worth every penny.)

Comment: That's proobably because many of us, including me, don't know enough French. My own levels isn't too high, but I think récupération is recovery and not recovering? Shouldn't recovering be récupérant (or something similar, ending with -ant?)

Comment: @YosefBaskin I'm not sure Google Translate is as reliable as you think! I have a degree in French, and  _une bonne récupération samedi_ doesn't look like idiomatic French to me - it would have to be _une bonne samedi de récupération_.But Mathmath's correspondent may still have translated her own phrase incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "I wish you a good recovering Saturday" is garbage and completely non-idiomatic.

The long answer is that the "-ing" form as a participle adjective has the adjectival effect of "that which verbs" and as a gerund has the effect of "associated with".

Thus

1 As a participle adjective: A "marking tool" is a tool that marks something, and a "cutting edge" is an edge that cuts.

2 As a gerund: A "walking stick" is not a stick that walks - it is something associated with walking and a "parking bay" is not a bay that parks but a bay associated with parking.

The question now is "how will "recovering Saturday" be understood?" It so happens that "recovering" will be understood as a participle rather than a gerund - A Saturday that recovers". This is because native speakers would expect you to use the deverbal noun "recovery" rather than the gerund "recovering" because there are also other noun compounds with "recovery in them: Recovery craft, recovery operation, etc.

> I still want to check the grammatical correctness of this sentence.

Either this is (i) a pointless exercise as the phrase is not idiomatic, should never be used, and will be misunderstood, or (ii) you have misunderstood the word "grammatical".

Famously "**Colorless green ideas sleep furiously**" is a sentence composed by Noam Chomsky in his 1957 book Syntactic Structures as an example of a sentence that is grammatically correct, but semantically nonsensical. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorless_green_ideas_sleep_furiously)

Comment: Thanks - if she'd have instead written: "I wish you a good recovery day", would that be correct? Please see the edited question with the added details and more context.

Comment: @Mathmath No. That also mangles English and is not idiomatic at all. The idea of linking Saturday and recovery probably cannot be done by attributive adjectives: "I wish you" is also awkward. "Have a good Saturday recovering" is what I might have said.

Comment: Thanks again - I'm learning quite a bit from your answer and comments. I figured that I'd not say the way it was written to me, but perhaps you might like to cite some links where I could read more on these topics, e.g. I can't see why "I wish you a good recovery day" may be wrong? I know it's not used, but can't see what's wrong with it. I see your point of it distorting standard English and hence not being idiomatic, but I'm trying to see if people would understand and it'd be grammatically correct.

Comment: *but I'm trying to see if people would understand* without context, they would not *and it'd be grammatically correct.* Why are you interested in that?

Comment: @Mathmath *if she'd have instead written: "I wish you a good recovery day", would that be correct?* I think that it would be understandable - it is not a common collocation but it is understandable.